# How to search in filtered list of nested objects only

Tags: elasticsearch

this seems to be a complex one - not sure if it's possible to manage without scripting + I would like to be able to boost `name` or `value` fields.

Let's imagine the following documents:

```json
{
  "name":"Red Big Blue document",
  "nested_key_value_properties":[
    {
      "key":"description 1",
      "value":"red"
    },
    {
      "key":"description 2",
      "value":"big"
    },
    {
      "key":"description 3",
      "value":"blue"
    }
  ]
}

{
  "name":"Black Small Red document",
  "nested_key_value_properties":[
    {
      "key":"description 1",
      "value":"red"
    },
    {
      "key":"description 2",
      "value":"small"
    },
    {
      "key":"description 3",
      "value":"black"
    }
  ]
}

{
  "name":"Yellow Big Red document",
  "nested_key_value_properties":[
    {
      "key":"description 1",
      "value":"yellow"
    },
    {
      "key":"description 2",
      "value":"big"
    },
    {
      "key":"description 3",
      "value":"red"
    }
  ]
}
```

I wish to get the documents that have the key `description 1` of the value of `red` only (first and second document) - the last document should not be in results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TLDR;

`Elastic` flatten objects. Such that

```json
{
  "group" : "fans",
  "user" : [ 
    {
      "first" : "John",
      "last" :  "Smith"
    },
    {
      "first" : "Alice",
      "last" :  "White"
    }
  ]
}
```

Turn into:

```json
{
  "group" :        "fans",
  "user.first" : [ "alice", "john" ],
  "user.last" :  [ "smith", "white" ]
}
```

To avoid that you need to set the mapping manually by telling that `nested_key_value_properties`  is going to be a nested field.
And then perform a nested query.

See below for how to do so.

## To reproduce

```json
PUT /71217348/
{
  "settings": {},
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "nested_key_value_properties": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "key": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"71217348"}}
{"name":"Red Big Blue document","nested_key_value_properties":[{"key":"description 1","value":"red"},{"key":"description 2","value":"big"},{"key":"description 3","value":"blue"}]}
{"index":{"_index":"71217348"}}
{"name":"Black Small Red document","nested_key_value_properties":[{"key":"description 1","value":"red"},{"key":"description 2","value":"small"},{"key":"description 3","value":"black"}]}
{"index":{"_index":"71217348"}}
{"name":"Yellow Big Red document","nested_key_value_properties":[{"key":"description 1","value":"yellow"},{"key":"description 2","value":"big"},{"key":"description 3","value":"red"}]}

GET /71217348/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "nested_key_value_properties",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "nested_key_value_properties.key": "description 1"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "nested_key_value_properties.value": "red"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nope, this what I had already and doesn't work - still 3 documents are returned (expectation is that only two will be in the results) but thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: Well.. I am surprised... When I run it.. I do have only 2 doc being returned.

Comment: Which version are you running ?

Comment: It is correct @Paulo

Comment: @Paulo "number" : "7.16.3", but I ran it once again and it is working now :)

Comment: Awesome folks !! Happy it worked.
@user18154574 have you identified what went wrong the first time ?

Comment: Actually I thought that if I `"include_in_root": true` on the nested field I can access it right from the must clause without putting `nested/path,query` - as I actualy use `should` as the top boolean condition and then i have several must clauses inside where I did not put `nested/path,query`.